# is it possible to ingore the class when deserialize json from redis in java

Tags: java, redis, deserialization

Now I am storing the app user info in redis, the data in redis look like this:

```
[
    "misc.contract.common.auth.LoginUserInfoDTO",
    {
        "userId": 92,
        "nickname": "u_qCX2J09hAB12",
        "avatarUrl": null,
        "autoRenewProductExpireTimeMs": null,
        "appName": "xSW5a4BbVB",
        "thirdBind": [
            "java.util.ArrayList",
            [
                [
                    "misc.contract.common.auth.ThirdBindInfo",
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "channelType": 2,
                        "userId": 92,
                        "thirdUserId": "2088402558023287"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

when I tried to read the data in spring boot like this:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.ValueOperations;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/post/")
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, LoginUserInfoDTO> redisTemplate;

    private ValueOperations<String, LoginUserInfoDTO> loginInfoRedis;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.loginInfoRedis = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
    }


    @GetMapping("/user")
    String getQRCodeUrl(){
        try {
            LoginUserInfoDTO dto = loginInfoRedis.get("REDDWARF_CV_WEB:user:detail:92");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
       return "hello world";
    }

}
```

shows error:

```
Could not read JSON: Could not resolve type id 'misc.contract.common.auth.LoginUserInfoDTO' as a subtype of `java.lang.Object`: no such class found
 at [Source: (byte[])"["misc.contract.common.auth.LoginUserInfoDTO",{"userId":92,"nickname":"u_qCX2J09hAB12","avatarUrl":null,"autoRenewProductExpireTimeMs":null,"appName":"xSW5a4BbVB","thirdBind":["java.util.ArrayList",[["misc.contract.common.auth.ThirdBindInfo",{"id":3,"channelType":2,"userId":92,"thirdUserId":"2088402558023287"}]]]}]"; line: 1, column: 47]
```

is that my `LoginUserInfoDTO` class not in the namespace `misc.contract.common.auth.LoginUserInfoDTO` cause this issue? is it possible to avoid this problem. For example, I saved the user info namespace is `misc.contract.common.auth.LoginUserInfoDTO`, the next version I changed the `LoginUserInfoDTO` class path, the new version of app could not parse the old version json? this issue will occure in the application runtime? if I only store a plan json without any class info, that is a better choice?

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: try to add this annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` with the java class. @The Maverick

Comment: Thanks @Dolphin. Today, I created a separate package for objects to share between services and it finally worked.